X11/Xlib - how gnome window menu (alt + space) work?
I develop X11/Xlib application on Ubuntu 20.04. When I press alt+space Gnome creates a window menu over my window. That window is not accessible, for example the following command doesn't show it:
watch -n 1 wmctrl -lG

Does Gnome create a normal window which is hidden or draw it using Xcomposite extension ?

I think you are running under Wayland. wmctrl can not manage non-X11 window.
